# wordpress page with php

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, contacts

i want to put a php script in to a page on a wordpress blog.
My server only supports a specifically script for emails through contact forms, so i need somehow to put the script in contact page. I've tryied to put that script in the page.php file but with no success.

Can anyone help me please?

Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file in your theme called 'contact_page.php' and put this code in it:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Contact Page
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
//Your code here
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Then create a new page in wordpress called "Contact" and set its' template as Contact Page

Comment: and how i set it's template as contact page? I'm currently using the twentyten theme. Sorry for being such a dumb ass

Comment: @tiago Not a problem man. Well when creating the page through wordpress admin, look on the right side you'll see "Page Attributes". You'll see template choices there. If you upload the code above to the twentyten theme folder correctly, you'll see Contact Page.

Comment: Alternatively, make a new page, remember it's ID and then create a page-ID.php file in your theme folder where ID is the numerical page id. It will basically do the same as setting the template through admin.

Comment: @code_burgar Interesting, I've never taken that route. I'm going to try that out.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using scripts you cannot get to work, why not use a Worpresss contact form plugin instead? There are really great plugins, such as for example Contact Form 7 that do the job perfectly and are really easy to include in your pages.

Comment: yeah i've tryied to use the Easy-Contact plugin, it is very simple too, but like i said, the server where the website is hosted do not allow other scripts. We must use their own script (security reasons they say)

Comment: Great alternative solution. On a few of my sites, nothing works but a hand code for me. I use CF7 when I can.

Comment: I see. Sorry about that. Try doing what brandenkeith suggested above, I upvoted his answer.